# How to clear html input related with php and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I set automatically clear my html input after click `enter`? It's complicated because my program uses ajax and php also. I tried to do this by jQuery `$("#txt").val('')` but then my input is clearing every single typed letter (I need to clear input only after click `enter`).

```
<html>
<body>
<div><label for="txt">Text:
<input id="txt" name="txt" type="text" value="" size="20"></label></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#txt").keyup(function(event) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13) 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'hello.php',
                data: {
                    func: 'test',
                    txtVal: $("#txt").val()
                },
                type: 'post',                                   
                });
              $("#txt").val('')
           });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problem with your if statement. Try to fix it with this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div><label for="txt">Text:
    <input id="txt" name="txt" type="text" value="" size="20"></label></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#txt").keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'hello.php',
                    data: {
                        func: 'test',
                        txtVal: $("#txt").val()
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                });
                $("#txt").val('')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to change this to `type: "POST"` as in jquery manual  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/